# How do I earn reputation if Stack Overflow is so good that I can always find my answer without posting a question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users, research

Stackoverflow has been instrumental in my career development; I've been using it for a long time and always found answers to my questions.

If every question I've ever had is already answered (directly or indirectly), how can I earn reputation?  Seriously, I think it is a testament to the excellent product (which I believe has helped every developer that has ever written a line of code since Stackoverflow has existed), but just when I think I've finally found a question worthy of asking, which has not already been asked in some fashion or other, I find an answer.  I've learned a lot over the course of a year but I can't even up-vote an answer for crying out loud!

How can I contribute to the community if the answers I need are always already on the site?

Comment: start sharing your knowledge with others and provide answers to questions.

Comment: Not being able to post on Meta is not a good reason to post crap here. **Knowing** that it's wrong beforehand just makes it worse. And after reaching the conclusion that every programming question possible has been asked on SO already (which is ridiculous), you should have checked if maybe someone already asked *this* question on Meta.

Comment: *... Stack Overflow is so good that I can always find my answer without posting a question* [citation needed]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*If every question I've ever had is already answered (directly or indirectly), how can I earn reputation?*

[By answering questions, of course!](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2958086/compass)

I've only asked 2 questions on Stack Overflow. And only one of those got an answer from another user. Everything else, I've self-taught or found solutions for through the system.

That doesn't prevent me from answering relatively [low-hanging fruit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471387/java-try-catch-issue/26471592#26471592) questions that are well within the average programmer's purview, or making an effort to delve into places unknown and [document the unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917641/java-calendar-returns-wrong-week/25918745#25918745).

Stack Overflow isn't designed with the intent that everyone be an asker. Someone has to answer the question too! And depending on the level of difficulty, a pay-it-forward mentality appears.

That being said, don't be out to answer obviously bad questions, and don't do people's homework for them.

All Stack Overflow asks from you to provide you the ability to upvote and comment is a small show of effort into helping the community. A single decent answer will [provide you enough reputation to do most of what you wish to do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). After that, you can continue answering questions for moderation powers, or just be content with the ability to upvote answers you find helpful.

Comment: Alright boys and girls.. The question that was posted and subsequently migrated was edited by the site. Censorship. A part of my question that was left out was critical to some of you overly zealous kids.. Particularly this point: If I need a minimal reputation to answer a question, but I have no reputation to begin with (and now I'm in the red) it will be difficult to get points.

But I have the information I need and I will refrain from posting anything until I spend a week or so checking posts to be sure my question has not already been answered. Thanks SO!!

Comment: Do you get any reputation points if you keep up voting good questions and answers?

Comment: @sunrise76 no you don't. You earn points through asking and answering.

Comment: One final doubt. Did you get any points if your comment is marked as useful through up vote?

Comment: @sunrise76 no, it's just to show helpful comments

Comment: @Mr.S Your post was not 'censored', the history is open for all to see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/278594/revisions) - That being said, none of what was removed was really relevant to your question, it's all backstory and a comment about not being able to post on meta (which is now irrelevant since it was migrated to meta). Also, you can't ever go in the red with reputation, you're hard-capped to 1. You're able to create questions and post answers on the main SO site.